# Hydrogen gas' reducing property

Tags: redox, hydrogen

I just went though a reaction wherein hydrogen gas is liberated and hence restricts the product formed to ferrous and not ferric salt. I just want to know how H2 gas gets its reducing property? It has a moderate bond strength also if I am not wrong.

Comment: "Liberation of hydrogen prevents the formation of ferric chloride."

Comment: When HCl reacts with Fe it is H+ which gets reduces and not H2 gas.

Comment: H+ reduces or gets reduced to H2?

Comment: H+ gets reduced to H2. Also the first comment is my textbook statement please see my views in my answer.

Comment: H+ gets reduced to H2. OK. But how can H2 in its gaseous state, reduce Fe+3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iron on reaction with HCl forms Fe(II) salts and not Fe(III) salts because even if Fe(+3) is formed, as we can see in electrochemical series Fe(+2) will be favoured ie. H2 which gets can reduce Fe(+3) to Fe(+2). So thermodynamically Fe(+2) salt is favoured. If you want to make Fe(+3) salt then you can react Fe and Cl2 directly.

> How H2 gets its reducing property?

H2 gas will react with FeCl3 to form FeCl2 and HCl. I don't know the exact mechanism but it can be explained well on the basis thermodynamic data available.

[image]

---

Comment: I agree with the answer. Just thought to say this- 'not in every condition though. At some conditions,may be the reverse reaction would be favoured(by Nernst equation)'

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal but the reaction is carried in a closed inert atmosphere of N2 so H2 evolved will not get liberated and react with Fe(+3).

Comment: I guess you are correct.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal inert atmosphere is required to prevent O2.